# Check sql match query

Tags: php, sql

I have a wordpress post title
$title = 'my post title';

I have a table called interlinks where I store all my post titles, urls, and siteurls or my entire network.

This query matches my title with all the titles in the interlinks table.

Please check if my query is correct. Thank you. I have a feeling it's a big buggy.

```
$query_related_posts_network = mysql_query(
   "SELECT "
   "   posttitle, "
   "   posturl, "
   "   siteurl, "
   "   MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') AS score "
   "FROM "
   "   interlinks "
   "WHERE "
   "   MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$title') AND "
   "   `siteurl` <> '$blogurl' "
   "LIMIT 15");
```

Comment: You probably want an `ORDER BY` clause to make sure you're getting the highest scoring matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see is:

Don't forget to escape the string variables you put in your SQL queries, using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
$query_related_posts_network = mysql_query("SELECT posttitle, posturl, siteurl,
  MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."') AS score
  FROM interlinks
  WHERE MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."')
    AND `siteurl` <> '".mysql_real_escape_string($blogurl)."' LIMIT 15");
```